# unit testing a sum in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, minitest

I want to create a test which tests if my method is working correctly.

The tonnage is calculated within my submission model and saved over there. I also need that function within my contest views and that's why I also included it in the contest model (is this correct?).

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions 

  def tonnage
    self.submissions.sum(:tonnage)
  end

end
```

When I test (minitest) I get following error:

```
FAIL["test_0003_must have tonnage", #<Class:0x007fbcb9fac260>, 2015-09-29 21:23:47 +0200]
 test_0003_must have tonnage#Contest (1443554627.17s)
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1 +1 @@
        -440
        +#<BigDecimal:7fbcbc9ac150,'0.0',9(27)>
        test/models/contest_test.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My test looks like this (minitest):

```
describe Contest do
  let(:contest) { Contest.create(name: "test",
                                 admin_id: 1,) }

  it "must have tonnage" do
    contest.tonnage.must_equal 440
  end


end
```

What does the test output mean (the failure) and what is the proper way to unit test this? I assume my method in my model is correct since it is working.

Thanks to the comment below I found out that I was referring to the wrong contest. Below is the proper test:

```
describe Contest do

  let (:default) { contests :default }

  it "must have tonnage" do
    default.tonnage.must_equal 440
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test shows

```
    -440
    +#<BigDecimal:7fbcbc9ac150,'0.0',9(27)>
```

Meaning that you expected `440` (as your test asserts) but you got a BigDecimal object with value `0.0`. Likely because this is the database column type with a `0.0` default.

My question: what is the `sum` message summing? Is it a column called `tonnage` ? Because I don't see that in your model. Is it a column called `tonnage` inside submissions? The logic for your sum is not correct.

Comment: The tonnage is calculated within the submission model and is saved over there. This is indeed saved within the column tonnage within submissions. How can I best handle this then since it is new for me?

Comment: Thanks for  your help, I was referring to the wrong contest, you made me see it!